# Cannot execute binary file (GCC for windows)

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm trying to compile the piece of assembly code below using gcc. I have finally got it to the point that it compiles an object file, but when I try and run it it get an error back saying 'cannot execute binary file'. I am on windows 10 version 1511.

I  am using the msys terminal and compiling by entering

```
gcc -c main.s -o main.o
```

I try and execute the file by entering

```
./main.o
```

And I get back the error

```
./main.o: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file
```

The assembly code is:

```
.section .text
    .global main
main:
    mov $4,%eax
    mov $1,%ebx
    mov $message,%ecx
    mov msglength,%edx
    int  $0x80

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
.section .data
    message: .ascii "Hello world!"
    msglength: .word 12
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you're just compiling, not linking. either `ld` will help, or don't specify .o in your output

Comment: it is not a case of specifying .o in the output, dont use -c on the compile

Comment: @dwelch if I don't use -c I get an error saying "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16 ... ld returned 1 exit status'.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Linux program and will not work on Windows.

As described in the comments, you need to link the program, remove `-c` from the `gcc` command line.

Comment: if I don't use -c I get an error saying "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16 ... ld returned 1 exit status'

Further, how do I link the files?